# How to insert into table yesterday date in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert into table yesterday's date. For current date I have this query:

```
    INSERT INTO FACILITY(Facility, LastPurge, CreatedBy, Active, RowVersionStamp)
VALUES ('AAA', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'engineer', '1', '7');
```

For the previous date, I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO FACILITY(Facility, LastPurge, CreatedBy, Active, RowVersionStamp)
VALUES ('AAA', DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY, 'engineer', '1', '7');
```

Above, does not work for me.
Thanks, in advance  for any help.

Comment: I have removed the irrelevant Mysql tag

Comment: In future please do not use the words "does not work". These are meaningless and convey no information. Instead please post the actual error that you get

Comment: Use DATEADD(day, -1,getdate())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use GetDate() - 1 - it will give you time also but if you need only date part then you can use cast(GetDate() - 1 as date)

```
INSERT INTO FACILITY(Facility, LastPurge, CreatedBy, Active, RowVersionStamp)
VALUES ('AAA', GetDate() - 1, 'engineer', '1', '7');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO FACILITY(Facility, LastPurge, CreatedBy, Active, RowVersionStamp)
VALUES ('AAA', DATEADD(day, -1,getdate()), 'engineer', '1', '7');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEADD()` function with `GETDATE()` :

```
INSERT INTO FACILITY(Facility, LastPurge, CreatedBy, Active, RowVersionStamp)
    SELECT 'AAA', DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 'engineer', '1', '7'
```

If the `Active` & `RowVersionStamp` has numeric type, then you don't need to use single quotes. If the `LastPurge` has `DATE` type instead of `DATETIME`, then use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` to convert into date format.

Comment: Thank you, it also works for me as  well as above solutions :)